# Inline equation breaks when adding Hebrew text with the witharrows package

Tags: babel, right-to-left, witharrows

I use Latex and `babel` to do my homework in Hebrew. I also use the `witharrows` package to make arrows explaining steps in equations. It usually works fine:

[image]

However, when I try to add Hebrew text to explain what I did, the inline equation in the `\Arrow{}` breaks and uses RTL direction, which is obviously wrong for math:

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Here's a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

% For Hebrew
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
% \babelprovide[main, import]{english}
% \babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{witharrows}

% witharrows options
\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle}

\tikzset{text=.}
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        font= \small
    }
}

\begin{document}
נחשב את הגבול
\( \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \):
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
    L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \\
    &= \lim_{x \to \infty} xP(x) e^{-x^2} \Arrow{\( Q(x) \coloneq xP(x) \) פולינום} \\
    &= \lim_{x \to \infty} Q(x) e^{-x^2}
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/285

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any explanation for that problem but, as workaround, you can put the equation in a `\hbox` of TeX.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

% For Hebrew
\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

% For English
% \babelprovide[main, import]{english}
% \babelprovide[import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}
\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}{David CLM}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{witharrows}

% witharrows options
\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle}

\tikzset{text=.}
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        font= \small
    }
}

\begin{document}
נחשב את הגבול
\( \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \):
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
    L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \\
    &= \lim_{x \to \infty} xP(x) e^{-x^2} \Arrow{\hbox{\( Q(x) \coloneq xP(x)\)} פולינום} \\
    &= \lim_{x \to \infty} Q(x) e^{-x^2}
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: while this works, I can't get the equation to show before the text. It keeps displaying as "Polynom Q(x)" instead of "Q(x) Polynom" no matter if I put the equation before or after the text.

Comment: I don't see `Q(x) Polynom` in your text...

Comment: I just translated it. "Polynom" is the word ״פולינום״ in the text

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. I’m trying to find a general solution, but below there is as a workaround (@f-pantigny almost got it). Why is this happening? Well, it’s related with the fact `\hbox`’es (a TeX primitive which shouldn’t be used at the user level) are used internally for quite a lot of purposed and there is no way to know if they contain real text or serve to build some special combination of letters, symbols, graphics, etc. `Babel` attempts to guess how to deal with them, but it may fail.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular, headfoot=hebrew]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{David CLM}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{witharrows}

% witharrows optionsפולינום
\WithArrowsOptions{displaystyle}

\tikzset{text=.}
\tikzset{
    WithArrows/arrow/.append style = {
        font= \small
    }
}

\begin{document}
נחשב את הגבול
\( \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \):
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
    L &= \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \\
    &= \lim_{x \to \infty} xP(x) e^{-x^2}
    \Arrow{\mbox{\(Q(x) \coloneq xP(x)\)} \mbox{פולינום}}\\
    &= \lim_{x \to \infty} Q(x) e^{-x^2}
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe `tikz` can use different macros for boxes that are meant for text, then `babel` can redefine those that are not meant for text from `hbox` to `hpack`.